# Melhor Linguagem/Biblioteca para manipular impressões

Tags: java, delphi

Aqui na empresa que eu trabalho, temos um sistema em clipper+PCL que faz as impressões mensais, com ele consiguimos manipular bandeja e controlar frente e verso. Porém esta cada vez mais difícil manter ele, isso pq temos que rodar ele num ambiente win 98, ou emular em um ambiente virtual.

Enfim, quero saber qual o melhor caminho para que seja feito esse novo sistema, se eu uso Java com Ireport ou até mesmo o Itext, ou Delphi(Rad Studio) com FastReport ou outra biblioteca ou até mesmo outra linguagem? Lembrando que a parte mais importante é a manipulação de bandeja e controle de frente e verso, hoje isso é feito no PCL das impressões.

Answer (score 1):

Só cabe a você escolher a melhor opção. Eu particularmente gosto do Delphi pelas partes prontas e ter menos que programar.

O caminho a ser pensado é na migração do banco de dados.

Meu conselho é fazer em paralelo e a sua nova aplicação ir tomando o local da antiga parcialmente até que esteja 100% testada para substituir.